I have made a JavaFX program using Eclipse, now how to create an executable?
I have a working JavaFX program developed in Eclipse with Maven.
I am using Java 17, JavaFX 17 non-modular.
I can run it using Run As -> Maven (clean javafx:run)
I now want to make an executable. But Export to Runnable JAR file does not work as I have no appropriate Launch configuration.
I saw another answer that used the maven-assembly-plugin with goals: clean compile assembly:single. That generates a runnable jar file, but on execution, nothing happens, and returns no errors. Does anyone have a direction for me to look? either with the Maven build system, or some other way to do this within Eclipse?

Start with the documentation. Then study the extensive list of resources found on the definition of the javafx tag that you used on this Question: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info. And search the existing  Questions and Answers.

Focus on the section on Packaging and your target system(s).
